# Вывод знаков после запятой в С# (Не округление)

Tags: c#, .net, вывод, числа-с-плавающей-точкой

Есть переменная double k = 2.46;

Как вывести в консоль число k и отбросить сотые?
Мне нужно чтобы в результате вывода было 2.4 без округления.

И если k = 2.0, то на выходе тоже было 2.0

Comment: `Math.Truncate(2.46 * 10) / 10`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В случае, если требуется изменить только представление числа, а не его значение, я бы рекомендовал использовать произвольное форматирование. Например:

```
Console.WriteLine(a.ToString("F1"));
```

выведет вам результат в виде десятичной дроби с одним знаком после запятой. Это будет работать для чисел, имеющих любую точность.

[Строки стандартных числовых форматов](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings)

Но заметьте, отбрасывая сотые, вы всё-таки **используете** округление, поэтому данный подход необходимо комбинировать с использованием метода `Math.Truncate`, выполняющим округление до ближайшего целого:

```
Console.WriteLine((Math.Truncate(a * 10) / 10).ToString("F1"));
```